# Swap 2 datetime cols based on condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 datetime cols 'date_a' and 'date_b' which I need to swap based on the condition below, but I'm getting error. What is the correct way to swap datetime columns?

```
    date_a      date_b
1   2020-09-01  2020-05-01
2   1992-01-01  1988-01-01
3   2013-10-01  2013-01-01

cond = df.date_a > df.date_b
df.loc[cond, ['date_a', 'date_b']] = df.loc[cond, ['date_b', 'date_a']].values

TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [float64]
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample to question?

Comment: There is typo in `['date_a ', 'date_b']` need `['date_a', 'date_b']` - remove space after `date_a`

Comment: excuse me but can you add sample data, by `.to_dict` method? then we could check more easily by copying and pasting dictionary from `. to_dict` method, and then put it into `pd.DataFrame` ~

Comment: @jezrael What I am curious about is the error. Shouldn't the error be like `column not found` or something similar (if he did a typeo)?

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat - ya, it will be nice. But seems in last pandas versions working correct, so it is bug in oldier pandas versions

Answer (score 1):

- there appears to by a typo in your code `df.loc[cond, ['date_a ', 'date_b']]` Do you really mean to create a new column **"date_a "**?
- have simulated data and it swaps dates based on condition

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df =pd.DataFrame({c:np.random.choice(pd.date_range("1-jan-2021",periods=40),10) for c in ['date_a', 'date_b'] })

cond = df.date_a > df.date_b
df.loc[cond, ['date_a', 'date_b']] = df.loc[cond, ['date_b', 'date_a']].values
```

#### using provided data

- no **TypeError**,  pandas 1.3.0

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
df =pd.DataFrame({c:np.random.choice(pd.date_range("1-jan-2021",periods=40),10) for c in ['date_a', 'date_b'] })
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""    date_a      date_b
1   2020-09-01  2020-05-01
2   1992-01-01  1988-01-01
3   2013-10-01  2013-01-01"""), sep="\s+")
df = df.assign(**{c:pd.to_datetime(df[c]) for c in df.columns})

cond = df.date_a > df.date_b
df.loc[cond, ['date_a', 'date_b']] = df.loc[cond, ['date_b', 'date_a']].values
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo

Comment: good point - I certainly don't get **TypeError** with or without possible typo

Comment: `TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [float64]`

Comment: have updated answer - no TypeError with data I simulated or data that was subsequently provided

Comment: Ya, not ypo error if `df.loc[cond, ['date_a', 'date_b']] = df.loc[cond, ['date_b', 'date_a']].values
`

Comment: If use `df.loc[cond, ['date_a ', 'date_b']] = df.loc[cond, ['date_b', 'date_a']].values
` no error?

Comment: OK, problem is in oldier pandas versions, tested in `1.2.3`

Comment: Yes, 'date_a ' was a typo and have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before and solved it as the following:

```
df[["date_a_", "date_b_"]] = df[["date_a", "date_b"]].rank(axis=1, method="first")
df[["date_a", "date_b"]] = np.where(df["date_a_"] == 2, [df["date_b"], df["date_a"]], [df["date_a"], df["date_b"]])
```